# Htaccess separate for Localhost and Production

Tags: .htaccess, localhost, production

How to create an Htaccess which will have a specific and separate code for Localhost and Production. I mean when we work on localhost, it should be work localhost code and in Production it should be load only Production code. So that i can use one Htaccess for Local and Production and it will save lot of time. Following is the model i would like to implement. It would be much appreciate anyone can help on this. Because i spend lot of time on it and not found any good approach on this. Thanks in Advance!

```
<Localhost>
---localhost code goes here 
---it should be only work in localhost and not at all in Production
</localhost>

<Production>
---production code goes here 
---it should be only work in Production and not at all in Localhost
</Producton>
```

Comment: This is not the idea behind a distributed configuration file. Those files are meant to resolve the application internal requirements. The general, domain specific setup should be done inside the http server's host configuration. So centralized, not distributed. It is important to keep domain specific and application specific rules apart.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you need that? Wouldn't that make debugging much harder? Which parts should really differ?

Comment: @NicoHaase When i setup HTTPS using Htaccess, I need it wok only in Production because, it will show error in localhost. Moreover i don't need htaccess caching in localhost but need in production. Hopes you understood my difficulties. I hope anybody can be comeup with this solution, it will be a worthfull solution for all of us. Because we should not much care on htaccess once this issue is solved.

Comment: Why not configure HTTPS in the core Apache configuration instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the code in `.htaccess` should be the same on local and production. (Otherwise, how do you test it?)

However, one of the cleanest ways to separate directives between servers is to `Define` (requires Apache 2.4) a variable in the server config of one of the servers (eg. the development machine):

```
Define DEVELOPMENT
```

This can be defined anywhere in the server config (not `.htaccess`), but is always seen as *global* to the server, regardless of whether it is defined inside a `<VirtualHost>` container or not. You do not need to specify a *value* (2nd) argument since the `<IfDefine>` directive (see below) does not check this. As always, whenever you make changes to the sever config you'll need to restart Apache for the changes to take effect.

And reference this in `.htaccess`:

```
<IfDefine DEVELOPMENT>
    # Local / development directives only
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine !DEVELOPMENT>
    # Live / production directives only
</IfDefine>
```

The `!` prefix tests that the variable is *not* defined.

Depending on what type of directives you need to contain you can use an `<If>` container and check something like the requested hostname (eg. `staging.example.com` vs `www.example.com` for the live site). However, `<If>` containers do not work the same with mod_rewrite.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#define

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the following, but it does not works. Let me know if i am wrong.

# local
<IfDefine DEVELOPMENT>
DirectoryIndex category.php
</IfDefine>

# remote
<IfDefine !DEVELOPMENT>
DirectoryIndex subcategory.php
</IfDefine>

Comment: @RenJitsm Have you defined the variable in the server config (not .htaccess) and restarted Apache?

Comment: I'm not much expert in PHP, can you share how to do it. Mine is just a Core Php project and don't have any config on it.

Comment: @RenJitsm This has nothing to do with PHP, this is Apache all the way. In your Apache server configuration file, or the `<VirtualHost>` container where you have defined your site (although _define's_ are always _global_) you need the directive `Define DEVELOPMENT` to actually define that variable. (The name `DEVELOPMENT` was just a suggestion, you may decide to call this `STAGING` or `LOCAL` if you prefer. Uppercase by convention only.) After making changes to the server config you need to restart Apache for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I use Apache Virtual Host and now i set a variable as you said using Define directive. Please check the following and let me know it is right.
    
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/projects/website/mgp/"
 Define DEVELOPMENT
    ServerName localhost.mgp
 <Directory "E:/projects/website/mgp">
     AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
`

Comment: @RenJitsm Yes, that's right. Note that variables defined in this way are always _global_ to the server, regardless of _where_ it is defined. It is not limited to that `<VirtualHost>` and will be accessible from _everywhere_. (So in that sense it may be more logical if it is defined in the main server config, outside of the vHost container - but it makes no difference in how it works.)

Comment: It Works! You are Amazing. I hope that i can ask you doubts by adding comment here. Let me know any other method to get your support. This is not only helpfull for me but for all Developers. Thank You Very Much for Your Wonderfull Help!.